# Sublime Text 3 Regular Expression (Line jump)

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to select a specific text on Sublime text, I looked for tutorials on how to do it but I can't find what I want.

As you can see on the screen, I'd like that **from a word, for example "hello", it selects the sentence where there is the word but also the 2 sentences underneath.**

Is it possible to do this?

[image: Screen Example]

in red represents the selection

Comment: Are you using the word `sentence` when what you mean is a `line`? Is this what you want: to use a RegEx to select the line a specific word is on and also the contents of the next 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the word 'sentence' when what you mean is a 'line' and what you want to do is to construct a RegEx to select the line a specific word is on and also the contents of the next 2 lines.

If that is right then the following regex does what you want and seems like what is shown in the screenshot that you posted.

```
(hello)(.*\n){2}(.*)
```

Comment: It works PERFECTLY, and yes I'm sorry for my bad English, but you understood exactly what I wanted.
Thank you again, and good evening, you're very kind!

Best Regards!